# How do I update an Array nested in a Hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

My script has:

```
my_hash = {'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => ['value2', 'value3']}
my_array = ["text...#{variable1}", "text...#{variable2}", "text...#{variable3}"]
my_hash['key2'] = my_array
```

I receive: `[]=': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)`.

How do I update the whole array for `key2`?

Comment: What did you try here?

Comment: I tried this: `my_array = ['value4', 'value5']` then `my_hash['key2'] = my_array`. I get `[]=': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)`

Comment: because you did not reference a key of the hash

Comment: 2.1.2 :001 > h = {}
 => {} 
2.1.2 :002 > h[:a] = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.1.2 :003 > h[:a]
 => [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Are you sure you want to update for `key2`, not `"key2"`?

Comment: `my_hash = {'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => ['value2', 'value3']}`

Comment: Are you sure this is where the error is happening?

Comment: I'm running on Adderral and 2 hours of sleep. I wasn't correctly parsing JSON into `my_hash`. It seems to be working. Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_array = ['value5']

hash = {
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => ['value2', 'value3']
}

hash['key2'] = new_array
```

Comment: When I do that, I get: `[]=': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)`.